# Rate of deceleration for an average speed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

I'm trying to figure out how to answer this problem:

> A car is driving at 11 m/s, when it begins to brake. Over the next 25 meters, it averages 6 m/s. At what rate does the car decelerate? Assume a constant rate of deceleration.

I understand how you would solve this problem if it needed to *reach* 6 m/s, but it has to *average* 6 m/s (or, to phrase it differently, cover the next 25 meters in 4.17 sec).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost all the way there.  You figured out that the "average speed" info gives you the time ($4.17s$) it takes for the car to cover $25m$.

Now all you have to do is find the acceleration.

You are probably familiar with the equation used in kinematics that describes the position of an object with constant acceleration:

$$x = x_0 + v_0 t + \frac{1}{2} a t^2$$

In this equation, $x$ represents the final position of the object, $x_0$ represents the initial position, $v_0$ is the initial speed of the object, $t$ is the time elapsed during the motion, and $a$ is the acceleration.

Plugging in the values that you know (using a coordinate system where the car starts at position $0m$ and ends at position $25m$)

$$25m  = 0m + (11m/s)(4.17s) + \frac{1}{2} a (4.17s)^2 $$

This can be solved for $a$.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I am actually new to physics (and haven't yet taken the class), so I wasn't aware of this equation. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You're welcome.  I added in an explanation of the variables in the equation.

Comment: Be careful: most likely this is the desired answer, but you can calculate the deceleration based on the average with respect to distance (instead of time).  This is an important distinction (as well as the concept behind the infamous quiz about driving 50 miles at 60mph and 50 miles at 40 mph and then calculating average speed)

Answer (score 0):

This can be made a little simpler by looking at how much the car's velocity changed over the period of the period of time it took to stop. That explains it conceptually but also shows it mathematically: division of velocity change by time it took to change. We can find the time it took to stop by:

StopTime = (Distance)/(AverageSpeed)

We then plug that into our original equation, along with our change in velocity (11 m/s to 0 m/s, a change of 11 m/s):

(ChangeInVelocity)/(StopTime) = AverageDeceleration

Which, since our deceleration is constant, equals our deceleration rate.